# Javascript Scope Issue Possibly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Having trouble with my variable 'html'. I think i have the scope correct but something weird happens when I run this code. the first alert of the 'html' variable produces a blank result and then I populate my select list with the same 'html' variable and it works, then i alert the 'html' variable again and the options show up.

If I remove the two alerts the list is not pop

```
function populateMakes(years)
{

    var makes = new Array();
    var html = "";

    $.each(years, function () {
        var uri = "/api/make?year=" + this;
        $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {             

            $.each(data, function () {
                if (jQuery.inArray(this.Id, makes) == -1)//makes not contain make
                {

                    makes.push(this.Id);

                    html += "<option value=" + this.Id + ">" + this.Value + "</option>";
                }

            });
        });

    });
    alert(html);
    $("#Make").html(html);
    alert(html);
    $("#MakeSection").removeClass("hidden");     


};
```

Document Ready Script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    populateYears();

    $("#Year").change(function () {
        $("#MakeSection").addClass('hidden');
        $("#ModelSection").addClass('hidden');
        $("#SubModelSection").addClass('hidden');

        populateMakes($("#Year").val());
    });

    $("#Make").change(function () {

        $("#ModelSection").addClass('hidden');
        $("#SubModelSection").addClass('hidden');

        populateModels($("#Year").val(), $("#Make").val());
    });

    $("#Model").change(function () {

        $("#SubModelSection").addClass('hidden');

       //
    });

    $("#Clear").click(function () {
        $("#YearSection").addClass('hidden');
        $("#MakeSection").addClass('hidden');
        $("#ModelSection").addClass('hidden');
        $("#SubModelSection").addClass('hidden');

        populateYears();
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.getJSON is async and i overlooked the timing. i needed to add the .done callback and set the output there. the script simply wasn't finished yet.

```
 $.getJSON(uri, function (data) {
            $.each(data, function () {
                if (jQuery.inArray(this.Id, makes) == -1)//makes not contain make
                {

                    makes.push(this.Id);

                    html += "<option value=" + this.Id + ">" + this.Value + "</option>";

                }

            });

        }).done(function () {
            $("#Make").html(html);
            $("#MakeSection").removeClass("hidden");
        });
```

I also didn't send an array in the event handler on the code I posted in the question. I fixed that first.

Comment: Glad you reached the answer yourself and posted it for others. It's an easy mistake to make.

Comment: I'm new to the async world. I'm figuring this out. NOW I am researching looping api calls and deffereds. my example here is actually not 100% how I want it even though it works. I want to wait until ALL calls are done before doing anything with the data.